# Magento shopping cart price rule buy 2 get 1 free

Tags: php, magento

I've been trying to setup this magento shopping cart price rule but fail.
So if customer buys 2 products of category 8, he/she gets the third one for free or if they buy 3 products from category 8, the cheapest one will be zero... is this possible?

I tried all kind of combination but none works

Comment: Could you show us what exactly you tried, what the the desired output for a certain input is and what went wrong in your attempts?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I tried this conditions: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  8  
Quantity in cart  equals or greater than 3 actions:  Apply percent of product price discount: 100

Discount Amount 1

Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0

Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0